# how to make youtube videos embed on your webpage when a link is posted

Tags: python, google-app-engine, youtube, youtube-api, jinja2

I have a website that gets a lot of links to youtube and similar sites and I wanted to know if there is anyway that I can make a link automatically appear as a video. Like what happens when you post a link to a video on facebook.  You can play it right on the page.  Is there a way to do this without users actually posting the entire embed video HTML code?

By the way I am using google app engine with python and jinja2 templating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each youtube video has a unique ID which is present in the url.

Examples here:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DU0Q0U08gAc&feature=g-all-esi
>
> http://youtu.be/DU0Q0U08gAc

In this case, `DU0Q0U08gAc` is the movie id.

This just gets inserted in the embed tag, as you can see here:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/DU0Q0U08gAc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So you need to parse the url for the id and insert it to an embed tag. I *believe* that in the case of `youtu.be` style links, it's just whatever's after the '/', and in the case of `youtube.com` links it's probably best practice to use the [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) library to get the 'v' variable from the url's query string. Hopefully someone will chime in if there's a corner case I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is Micawber...which is available in pure Python, as well as Django and Flask plugins.  Works nicely with Jinja. Embeds vids and pics into your app exactly like Facebook.  You can install it via pip.  Good docs; easy to follow examples.  The author is responsive to questions.  Works great, and it's totally free.  Check it out:

http://readthedocs.org/projects/micawber/

You can also check out http://oembed.com and http://embed.ly  ...although the latter is not free, and starts at $19/mo (as of July 2012).

Comment: where should I put it in my GAE project? just put the micawber-latest folder in the src file and the import it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code when getting embed link from list value. In the template inside the iframe use below code

src="{{results[0].video_link}}"

"video_link" is the Field name.